# extjs: add checkboxes to formpanel: wrong state

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got a `fromPanel` and i'm trying to do the follows:

```
var linkPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    ...
});
var records = layers_store.getRange();
for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var layer_checked;
    console.log(records[i].data);
    if(records[i].data.checked == 'true') {
        layer_checked = true;
    } else {
        layer_checked = false;
    }
    console.log(layer_checked);
    linkPanel.add(new Ext.form.Checkbox({
        boxLabel : records[i].data.layer_name,
        name : records[i].data.layer_name,
        checked : layer_checked,
        handler : ...
        }
    }));
}
```

And in another part of my code `layers_store` is being changed.

So what i have in console:

```
({layer_id:"1", layer_name:"\u041F\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044B\u0439", checked:"false"}) 
false 
({layer_id:"2", layer_name:"\u0412\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043E\u0439", checked:"true"}) 
true
```

What means that the first checkbox must be unchecked. **But** it remains checked.

What am i doing wrong?

**edit**:
[image]

Comment: Only first is checked? The rest is fine? Do you use checkboxes as radiobuttons with only one selected or no?

Comment: @sha, No, the problem is the same for all: i've used it here just as an example. Checkboxes are used as they are - not like radio.

Comment: Then it should work.. :) Try to log panel itself after all checkboxes are added - you can see items inside it from the debug.

Comment: @sha added a picture... it seems wired, i don't know what can it be =)

Answer (score 1):

This answer could really depend on what version of ExtJS you are using. I will assume that is the 4.0 version.

Since Ext.data.Store's getRange() method returns an array of records, objects of type Ext.data.Model, you won't really be able to access it's properties as if they were indexes of a simple array.

Try accessing them like this:

```
records[i].get('layer_id'); 
records[i].get('layer_name'); 
records[i].get('checked');
```

Comment: i'm using 3.4 version and this change gave me nothing

Comment: In that case, the returned array has objects of type Ext.data.Record, am I right? Anyways, I think the problem lives in the part of the code  that you are actually trying to get the checked property. Try debugging that value in the console.

Comment: i've done this: see my question. the `layer_checked` var contains what i need. maybe i need to refresh the form somehow?

Comment: Nah, I don't think that's the problem, but you could try anyways, with   linkedPanel.renderTo(Ext.getBody()).